# Does this notion of "continuity" for a sheaf of algebras make sense?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space, let $R$ a commutative ring. All algebras are required to be commutative unital associative, and algebra morphisms are required to be unital.

Let us say a sheaf $\mathcal{O}$ of $R$-algebras on $X$ is "continuous" if for every open $U \subset X$, for every $f \in \mathcal{O}(U)$, for every $x \in U$, there is a *unique* element $\lambda \in R$ such that $f-\lambda$ is non-invertible in every open neighborhood of $x$ (contained in $U$).

Would this definition be a sensible one? (My apologies if there is already a better notion of a "continuity" property for sheaves, or if this definition is flawed.)

---

For examples:

I think I've managed to show every sheaf of *local* $k$-algebras, for $k$ an algebraically closed field, is continuous.

Also, the sheaf of all continuous $F$-valued functions on $X$, where $F$ is any Hausdorff *topological* field, appears to be continuous; and I think any $F$-subalgebra-sub-sheaf of this would also be continuous.

(Are these correct? Could anyone weigh in on these?)

---

I was wondering if anyone could give an example of an "interesting" sheaf which is *not* continuous? (For example, I believe the sheaf of *all* real-valued, functions not necessarily continuous, would fail to be continuous; but is there a more "restrictive" sheaf which fails to be continuous?)

Edit: added above a requirement for $F$ to be Hausdorff; I think we need at least its points to be closed.

Comment: What is your motivation? What's 'continuous' about your continuous sheaves?

Comment: I'm not sure if "continuous" is the right definition, but the above property seems to hold for a wide selection of "nice" sheaves of rings, like continuous real funcs, and smooth and anlytic funcs on a mfld (more generally cont/smooth sections of cont/smooth fiber bundles); and also (if I'm not mistaken) complex schemes in general.

Comment: The more interesting question is whether anything worthwhile follows for sheaves satisfying your definition. Also, I am not sure whether it holds for a wide selection of sheaves. For instance, it is not preserved by products of sheaves. Also, it seems very close to requiring that the stalk at each point is a local $R$-algebra.

Comment: I see, thank you for the insight; I will think more about the relationship between the above property and the property of having local $R$-algebra stalks.

Comment: I find it highly unlikely that this would be a reasonable definition because it is not “local”. In other words, we may have an open cover $\{U_i \mid i \in I\}$ of $X$ and a sheaf $F$ where for all $i \in I$, $F|_{U_i}$ is a continuous sheaf on $U_i$, but where $F$ is not a continuous sheaf on $X$.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion; would you be able to provide an example of such a sheaf and open covering?

Comment: @IndraneelTambe Consider $X = \{0, 1\}$ with the discrete topology. Let $R = \mathbb{R}$; then $F(U) = R^U$ gives us a sheaf which is locally continuous but not continuous.

Comment: Sorry, could you give a particular $U,f,x$ in your example for which the property I defined fails? I can't seem to find one

Comment: @IndraneelTambe I misread the original version of your question, but with your new version, everything looks reasonable. I will provide a more thorough answer to your other question.

Comment: @IndraneelTambe: You are assuming $R$ is a field, I think.  If $X$ is nonempty discrete and $F(U)=R^U$, then I would expect $F$ to be continuous.  Not so when $R=\mathbb{Z}$: there are always many $\lambda$ for which $(f-\lambda)(x)\notin\{\pm1\}=U(\mathbb{Z})$, and thus $\lambda$ is never chosen _uniquely_.

Comment: I think you can recover the nonfield case by changing "noninvertible" to "topological zero divisor", but I'm not 100% confident.

Comment: Thank you for the insights! I will think some more about these